# How to export files from Oracle Apex workspace using command line?

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5, oracle-apex-5.1

One simpler way is:

Go to https://apex.oraclecorp.com then login into the workspace using credentials.After that click on SQL scripts and proceed to download or export the SQL's.

But is there any way by which we can directly export/download all the sql files via **command line** ?

Answer (score 1):

You can quickly export Apex applications through the command line, avoiding the Apex UI completely. To do this, Oracle has provided two java classes, which are included in the Apex download:

- APEXExport.class
- APEXExportSplitter.class

These classes are located in the apex/utilities/oracle/apex directory.

Before using these classes, you have to make sure that the following environment variables are set up correctly:

**ORACLE_HOME** should point to just that. Something like:

/u01/app/oracle11g/product/11.2.0/db1

**APEX_HOME** should point to the directory where you unzipped the Apex download. For example

/u01/downloads/apex

**PATH** needs to include $ORACLE_HOME/jdk/bin

**CLASSPATH** needs to include:

- $ORACLE_HOME/jdbc/lib/ojdbc5.jar
- $APEX_HOME/utilities

Note: You may also have to include the . path.

**APEXExport**

To execute the export use

$ java oracle.apex.APEXExport

You can get a list of the available arguments by executing the above command without arguments. For a basic application export use:

$ java oracle.apex.APEXExport  -db localhost:1521:db1 -user scott -password tiger -applicationid 100

You’ll get a message saying: Exporting application 100.

Once the export is done you’ll see an *sql file in your current directory (e.g. f100.sql).

**APEXExportSplitter**

You can now take the export file and split it up into its various components. This is handy if, for example, you want to examine the SQL of an application page or two.

$ java oracle.apex.APEXExportSplitter f100.sql

This program creates a directory named after your application (e.g. f100) and multiple sub directories which contain the various components of the application.

Comment: What you wrote is correct (at least, I think so), but - you missed the point. The OP didn't ask how to export an application, but how to export **files** - when you logon into Apex, pick "SQL Workshop" dropdown menu at the top of the screen. In there, you'll see **SQL Scripts** - click on it. Now you'll see scripts you have. On the right hand side of the screen, there's the **Export** task which performs export, but that's GUI. The OP wants to do the same from the command prompt. And that's certainly not what you described.